# Can I update styles in Material-UI without component rerendering?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styles, display

I have a **Box component**. I need to hide it if **props** are false and show if one of them is true. But when **props** are true, it is hidden. And when I switch to **another component** and return to those with boxes, it becomes visible.

```
<Box                              
        component={Grid}
        display={{
          xs: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
          sm: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
          md: "block",
        }}
       
      >
        <Component/>
      </Box>
```

I know, that I can use condition and everything will be ok.

```
 { any condition &&
         <Box                              
            component={Grid}
            display={{
              xs: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
              sm: error || activity ? "block" : "none",
              md: "block",
            }}
          >
            <Component/>
          </Box> 
  }
```

or write displayStyle and use breakpoint in styles

```
const displayStyle =  error || activity ? "block" : "none",  

 <Box                              
        component={Grid}
        display={displayStyle}
       
      >
        <Component/>
      </Box>
```

But can I change **display** by updating styles of MaterialUI

Comment: Could you describe more about your question? Do you want to change `display` in the `Box` component? What do you mean by `styles of MaterialUI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Material-UI Hook `makeStyles`, would look something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: { display: props => props.error ? 'block' : 'none' },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

Or you can use `styled-components`, personally I find it more satisfying, would look something like this:

```
const MyButton = styled(Button)({
  display: ${(props) => props.error ? 'block' : 'none' }
});

export default function StyledComponents() {
  return <MyButton>Styled Components</MyButton>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I need display change according display size? If it is downMD it should be **block** or **none**.

Comment: Valerxx22, I use class component, but it does not matter. I rewrite it for class component.  It helped. Thank you.